# Meteor - Test application using local package over the published one

Tags: meteor, package

I'm using Meteor 0.9.3, and I want to try to make some changes to a Meteor smart package.  I'm using the package in my app already, let's call it: author:smartpackage.

First, I removed my reference to the published package:

```
meteor remove author:smartpackage
```

I've forked the repository on GitHub, and made a local clone in:

```
/somedir/meteor-smartpackage/
```

I've created a directory in my meteor app:

```
/meteor/myApp/packages
```

and created a symlink:

```
ln -s /somedir/meteor-smartpackage /meteor/myApp/packages/meteor-smartpackage
```

How do I now add this local package into my app? I've tried a variety of

```
meteor add xxxx
```

options, but I can't find the right command.  Am I even close?

Comment: See my post on [local packages](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/local-packages). It explains how to do this with an environment variable. You may need to do `meteor add author:smartpackage` instead of `meteor add smartpackage` depending on what is in the `package.js`.

Comment: Thanks David - that was a great help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The steps you described look good to me, so maybe this is the symlink stuff which is messing around.

The proper way of maintaining private packages is to have a `packages/` directory somewhere in your filesystem, let's say in `~/meteor/packages`, then you have to set a special environment variable that is called `PACKAGE_DIRS`, which is looked up by the meteor command line tool to find local packages that reside out of official package repositories.

So let's set this environment variable in your `.bashrc` and resource it :

```
echo "export PACKAGE_DIRS=$HOME/meteor/packages" >> ~/.bashrc;
. ~/.bashrc
```

Then assuming your forked package resides in `~/meteor/packages`, `meteor add author:package` should work normally.

Comment: I removed the symlink, and added the environment variable and it's now working - thanks

Comment: Running Meteor 1.1.0.3: This isn't working for me at all. It appears to be ignoring the local PACKAGE_DIRS and just going to get the published version regardless. Is there different bahavior in the latest version of the command line tool perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

Update to saimeunt's answer, for Meteor 1.2+
I found that loading the local package requires leaving out the author when running `meteor add`.

Loads Local Package
`meteor add cocos2d-meteor`

Loads Remote Package
`meteor add jakelin:cocos2d-meteor`